# How to add the image from local windows machine to browser using AutoItLibrary in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to upload an image from the local windows machine to the chrome browser using AutoItLibrary
Here is the code which I have used

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    BuiltIn
Library    AutoItLibrary
*** Variables ***
${Image_file}                C:\\Users\\gopikpa\\Desktop\\dog_images.JPEG

*** Keywords ***
 Wait For Active Window    Open
   Control Set Text        Open    ${EMPTY}    Edit1    ${Image_file}
Control Click          Open    ${EMPTY}    Button1

*** Test Cases ***
[TC-001]-Launch the AEM Website
```

I am getting result as

```
[TC-001]-Launch the AEM Website                                       | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Control Set Text' found.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Assertupload                                                          | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

Comment: Please edit you question to make it readable and understandable.

Comment: The provided code example is incomplete which makes it harder to help you. The keyword `Uplod Image to the Dam` isn't present and the formatting of the keywords makes it difficult to distinguish the keyword name from it's contents, I even think this might be the missing keyword. So, please edit your question and add these details. Please also add the `*** Settings ***` section for the relevant library imports.

Comment: @A.Kooststra can you have a look and help me

Comment: @llhicas Can you have  a look at the code